# Swift rest client is making slow connections

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a performance problem implementing a `REST` client related with long delays. Problem is not present on my `Android` app or any `REST client` adding to browsers so it is not related with backend issues.

this is my function for executing `API` call:

```
func getRecordsMethod(completion: @escaping ((_ result: Data) -> Void)){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let username = defaults.object(forKey: "username") as! String
        let password = defaults.object(forKey: "password") as! String
        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password).description
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let base64LoginString = loginData?.base64EncodedString()
        let url = URL (string: apiURL + getPersonalBests )
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Basic " + base64LoginString!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {
                completion(data!)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

and how I call it in my `ViewController` :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        populateRecords()
}
func populateRecords(){


    self.records.removeAll()
    apiRestManager.getRecordsMethod() {
        (result: Data) in
        let json = JSON(data: result)
        for (_, subJson) in json {
            // processing response- adding to personalBestTable
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.personalBestTable.reloadData()
        }

    }




}
```

The biggest issue is that after function `populateRecords` is being started there is delay approx 2-3 seconds after a call is visible on my backend (after that processing and table reload is made instantly)

Can anyone give me a hint how I can optimize requests speed?

Comment: I think your problem is parsing the data to JSON rather than hitting your server. Can you please remove the mapping and check how long would it take for your callback to be called?

Comment: @Greg Gregorowski: Thats strange! There is nothing wrong in the code of API Manager. I believe populateRecords is called in background thread. Is the thread context switching taking time ?

Comment: @EridB I have removed JSON processing completely, it did not solve the issue

Comment: @SandeepBhandari from the code snippet I pasted You can probably tell that I am newbie swift programmer :) I have no idea how to check if method is called in background thread or how to check if it is context switching that takes so long :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the data from `UserDefault` on main threat may cause the delay.

Change your `viewDidLoad` method with following code

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "apiQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

             concurrentQueue.async {
                    populateRecords()
             }
        }
```

Comment: it did improve (not so much but still). And I agree that delay is related with getting data from `UserDefault`. Is there any smart way to load once data from `UserDefault` and use it in multiple `ViewController's` ?

Comment: Create some manager class with property like `NSMutableDictionary`. Once you got the data from `UserDefault` save it in manager class dictionary. Loading data from `Memory` is faster than loading data from '`UserDefault`